# Failed to compile judge: judge.java:1: error: class, interface, or enum expected 1

Tags: java

This is the question link of Google Code Jam Round 1A: https://codingcompetitions.withgoogle.com/codejam/round/0000000000877ba5/0000000000aa8fc1

I am trying to take input but I am getting this error :
Failed to compile judge: judge.java:1: error: class, interface, or enum expected
1

This is the code :

import java.io.*;

import java.util.*;

class Solution{

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    int t = sc.nextInt();
    
    for(int k=1; k<=t; k++){
        
        int n = sc.nextInt();
        int[] arr = new int[2*n];
        int i=0;
        for(; i<n; i++){
            
            arr[i] = i+1;
            System.out.print(arr[i]+" ");
        }
        for(; i<2*n; i++) arr[i] = sc.nextInt();
    }
}
```

}

Please tell me, Why am I getting error?

Comment: `import java.io.;` is not valid in Java - probably you did mean `import java.io.*;` (same for second import)

Comment: I have also used import java.io.*;

Answer (score 0):

for(; i<2*n; i++) arr[i] = sc.nextInt();

this is probably your problem

Comment: its ugly but legit